# Syntax Error in python Wifi Module

Tags: python, syntax-error, wifi, cell

So I am trying to use python's wifi module to get neary wireless networks and log into them using a password.  So far this is  my code just to get the networks...

```
from wifi import Cell, Scheme

Cell.all('interfacename')
```

And I am receiving the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 1, in <module>
File "/goval_modules/python3.6/pbkdf2/__init__.py", line 69
    print pbkdf2(p, s, l, i).encode('base64')
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone please help me understand why this error is appearing and how to fix it?

Comment: You are executing a python2+-written script with python3+.

Comment: I'm afraid that putting parentheses around `print` won't be enough ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kanak mentioned, this WiFi module was written in python2, but you are using it in python3. Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this.

One possible fix could be trying to find an updated version of this module. You could also write your code in python2, but that might be a bit impractical.